# Android ListView: Modifying One Row Affects Other Rows

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I currently making a Activity containing a ListView with a ImageView as an checkbox which will change if the user taps on the ImageView of the row. The problem is that when selecting one row modifying its ImageView, but after browsing a few rows (8 to be exact), I see that this row had its ImageView also modified.

Here are some of the relevant code:

HistoryRowAdapter.java

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_row, parent, false);
        convertView.setTag(getItemId(position));
    }

    final Operation currentOperation = getItem(position);
    //Log.d("KS", "Name: " + currentOperation.toString());

    DBTools db = new DBTools(getContext());
    HashMap<String,String> patientData = db.getPatientData(currentOperation.getId());

    String patientName = "N/A";
    if (Integer.parseInt(patientData.get("id")) != -1){
        //Patient Data was entered

        String lastName = patientData.get("last_name");
        String firstName = patientData.get("first_name");
        patientName = lastName.length()!=0 && firstName.length()!=0 ? lastName+", "+firstName.charAt(0): "N/A";
    }

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameFieldTextView);
    nameTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    nameTextView.setText(patientName);

    String[] dateTime = currentOperation.getDatetime().split("_");

    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateFieldTextView);
    dateTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    dateTextView.setText(dateTime[0]);

    dateTime[1] = dateTime[1].replace("-",":");
    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeFieldTextView);
    timeTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    timeTextView.setText(dateTime[1]);

    final ProgressDialog loading = new ProgressDialog(context);
    loading.setMessage("Loading Procedure...");
    loading.setCancelable(false);
    loading.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    Button viewOperationButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewOperationButton);
    viewOperationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ReviewMode.class);
            i.putExtra("selectedOperation",currentOperation.getId());
            i.putExtra("deviceStatus",0);
            loading.show();
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    /*ImageView checkedImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.checkedImageView);
    for (int i = 0; i< itemsSelected.size(); i++){
        if(position == itemsSelected.get(i)){
            checkedImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_row);
        }
    }*/


    return convertView;
}
```

Function that "checks" the row:

```
public View getViewByPosition(int position, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}

public void buttonSelect(){
    if (this.highlightedIndex != -1){
        int firstRow = proceduresListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int lastRow = proceduresListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
        Log.d("KS","First Row: "+firstRow);
        Log.d("KS","Last Row: "+lastRow);
        //RelativeLayout highlightedRow = (RelativeLayout) proceduresListView.getChildAt(proceduresListView.getCheckedItemPosition()%7);
        Log.d("KS","Checked:"+proceduresListView.getCheckedItemPosition());
        RelativeLayout highlightedRow = (RelativeLayout) getViewByPosition(proceduresListView.getCheckedItemPosition(), proceduresListView);
        Log.d("KS","Selected:"+this.highlightedIndex);
        ImageView checkboxRow = (ImageView) highlightedRow.findViewById(R.id.checkedImageView);

        if (selectedItems.contains(this.highlightedIndex)){
            Log.d("KS","Items: "+selectedItems.toString());
            checkboxRow.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_row);
            //selectedItems.remove(this.highlightedIndex);
            selectedItems.remove(selectedItems.indexOf(this.highlightedIndex));
        } else {
            checkboxRow.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_row);
            selectedItems.add(this.highlightedIndex);
            Log.d("KS","Items: "+selectedItems.toString());
        }

        checkedCountTextView.setText(selectedItems.size()+"");
        //Log.d("KS", "Select: " + highlightedIndex);
        //Log.d("KS","Items: "+selectedItems.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [holder pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder)